# Assigning Multiple ips to a NIC using powershell

Tags: powershell-3.0, nic, dynamic-ip

I am trying to assign multiple ips to a NIC on a windows server. Is there any way I could dynamically generate the ip addresses and assign it to the NIC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to call the [`EnableStatic`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa390383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method on the instance of the [`Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394217%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class for the network interface you want to configure.

```
uint32 EnableStatic(
  [in]  string IPAddress[],
  [in]  string SubnetMask[]
);
```

You can see above it takes two parameters. A string array of IP addresses and a string array of subnet masks.

It will return an status code. 0 indicates success.

Here is PowerShell example code:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -Filter "IPEnabled=true" | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $result = $_.EnableStatic(("192.168.1.10","10.0.0.10"),("255.255.255.0","255.0.0.0"))
        if ($result -ne 0) {
            # handle non-successful response code here.
        }
    }
```